# Group together celery results

Tags: python-3.x, celery

TL:DR
I want to lable results in the backend.

I have a flask/celery project and I'm new to celery.
A user sends in a batch of tasks for celery to work on.
Celery saves the results to a backend SQL database (table automatically created by Celery, named celery_taskmeta).

I want to let the user see the status of his batch, and request the results from the backend.

My problem is that all the results are in one table. What are my options to lable this batch, so the user can differentiate the batches?

My ideas:

- Can I add a lable to each task, e.g. "Bob's batch no. 12" and then query `celery_taskmeta` for that?
- Can I put each batch in named backend tables, so ask Celery to save results to a table named `task_12`?

#### Trying with groups

I've tried the following code to group the results

```py
job_group = group(api_get.delay(url) for url in urllist)
```

But I don't see any way to identify the group in the backend/results DB
[image]

#### Trying with task name

In the backend I see an empty column header 'name' so I thought I could add an arbitrary string there:

```py
@app.task(name="an amazing vegetable")
def api_get(url: str) -> tuple:
...
```

But then the celery worker throws an error when I run the task:

```
KeyError: 'an amazing vegetable'
[2020-12-18 12:07:22,713: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'an amazing vegetable'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution is to use [Group](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#groups) and use the [Group Result](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#group-results) to periodically poll for group state.

A1: As for the label question - yes, you can "label" your task by using the [custom state](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states) feature.

A2: you can hack around to put each batch of tasks inside backend table, but I strongly advise not to mess with it. If you really want to go this route, make a separate database for this particular use.

Comment: Hi @DejanLekic, Ive tried group and updated my question.
I looked at A1, vustom state, but I would prefer not to do that, since I want to use the default states.